# Calculate a double integral over a region.

Tags: calculus, integration, multiple-integral

> Calculate $\iint\limits_Gf(x;y)$ where
>   $$
> f(x;y)=\frac{y}{x},\ \ G=\{x\geqslant0,\ y\geqslant0,\ 1\leqslant xy\leqslant 5,\ \frac{x}{2}\leqslant y\leqslant2x\}
> $$

I tried to plot the function that $G$ provides and got something like this:

[image]

However, I don't think that it is easy to find boundaries for $x$ and $y$ in order to convert given double integral into an iterated one. So, is there any better solution to this problem?

Comment: Consider converting to [hyperbolic coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_coordinates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u(x,y) = xy, v(x,y) = y/x$ and use the change of variables theorem.

Answer (score 1):

In polar coordinates, the region is

$$1\le r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta\le 5, \>\>\>\>\>\frac12\le \tan\theta \le 2$$

and $f(r,\theta)=\tan\theta$. So, with the limits,

$$\theta_1= \tan^{-1}\frac12,\>\>\>\>\> \theta_2= \tan^{-1}2,
\>\>\>\>\>r_1^2(\theta)=\frac1{\sin\theta\cos\theta},
\>\>\>\>\>r_2^2(\theta)=\frac5{\sin\theta\cos\theta}$$

the integral is

$$I= \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} 
\int_{r_1(\theta)}^{r_2(\theta)} \tan\theta rdrd\theta 
=2 \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \frac{\tan\theta}{\sin\theta\cos\theta}d\theta$$
$$=2\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \sec^2\theta d\theta
=2\tan\theta|_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}=2(2-\frac12)=3$$

Comment: Could you explain what $r_1(\theta)$ and $r_2(\theta)$ are?

Comment: @Bonrey - They are from the boundary equations, $r_1^2(\theta) = \frac1{\sin\theta\cos\theta}$ and $r_2^2(\theta) = \frac5{\sin\theta\cos\theta}$